# Distance matrixes and ports positions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I have port positions and need to generate distance matrixes in nautical miles. I am using Proximity tool of ArcGIS for obtaining distances but in this case it doesnt work as I have restrictions i.e. I dont want the linear distance between two ports crossing land....what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Are you dealing with ports world-wide or in a more restricted geography?  Be sure to answer by editing this detail into your question rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

A related question was asked on the ArcGIS forums in June 2013: [A question on depicting ship routing in ArcMap 10.1](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/87667-A-question-on-depicting-ship-routing-in-ArcMap-10.1?highlight=islands). It includes a link to a custom model written by John Fry. The tool makes use of Spatial Analyst's Cost Distance tool. The resulting cost matrix raster has pixels = 1 for water and 0 for land.